# Internal parallelization by CPU

Tags: c++, c, performance, prng

I've been playing around with Xorshift* random number generators, and I came across [this](http://xorshift.di.unimi.it/) exploration of their properties. Quoting from that site (emphasis mine):

> How can a xorshift64* generator be slower than a xorshift1024* generator?
>
> Dependencies. The three xor/shifts of a xorshift64* generator must be executed sequentially, as each one is dependent on the result of the previous one. In a xorshift1024* generator two of the xor/shifts are completely independent and **can be parallelized internally by the CPU**. I also suspect that the larger state space makes it possible for the CPU to perform more aggressively speculative execution (indeed, a xorshift128* generator is slower than a xorshift1024* generator).

What does this parallelization internally by the CPU statement mean? I took it to mean that the CPU would use vector instructions to execute the two xor/shifts concurrently, but I haven't been able to see evidence of this in the assembly output by the compiler. Is this a deep CPU pipelining thing? Or should I be able to see something going on in the produced assembler?

Comment: [Superscalar CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar) have multiple execution units and long-ish pipelines - reducing serial dependencies enables more parallelism by keeping more execution units busy. So if you have two ALUs you can get twice the throughput if you keep both of them busy.

Comment: A CPU has multiple execution ports inside of a single code / thread. When there are not dependencies between instructions several instructions can be run on the same clock.

Comment: This is not compile time generated parallelism, but  parallelism generated by the CPU at runtime, when it sees that several instructions in a block have no dependencies.

Comment: BTW, this CPU parallelism is called instruction level parallelism.

Comment: @didierc Then how to make the CPU see more independent instructions? Aren't they compile time generated? Isn't it compiler's job to remove unnecessary dependencies?

Comment: @user3528438 you are totally correct. The compiler will try to order instructions in way which help the CPU notice these situations. A CPU usually has a limited instruction cache for execution (the cache that stores instruction lined up to be executed in the coming cycles), and it cannot check dependency outside that cache, and the already executing instructions. It's also the compiler's job to merge set of instructions into vector (SIMD) instr. when possible.

Comment: @user3528438 I'm not sure that a CPU woud synthetize SIMD exactly as a compiler would, but running 4 instructions which could be merged in a single SIMD would probably turn up to become the same CPU state: 4 instructions running concurrently in the CPU pipeline, but hitting 4 different registers, rather than a single vector register. Could 4 gen. reg. be aliased to a single vector register, I don't know (well, on x86, mmx and fp regs were strongly aliased, but not in that way).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's an [instruction-level parallelism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism) thing.

Basically such a CPU will have more execution hardware available than is needed for each individual instruction, so it "spreads out" a bunch of instructions over the available resources, then merges the results back so that, to the programmer, it still looks like things are happening sequentially.

What you can see, if you're good at it, is two adjacent instructions that both do work, but that have no dependency. For instance they might be operating on non-overlapping sets of registers only. For such cases, you can guess they might be executed in parallel, resulting in a high instructions-per-cycle value for that particular bit of code.

To make this a bit more concrete, let's look at the two pieces of code you're talking about (also: learning opportunity for me).

Here's the core of xorshift64*:

```
x ^= x >> 12; // a
x ^= x << 25; // b
x ^= x >> 27; // c
return x * 2685821657736338717LL;
```

Actually, that's all the code in the function (`x` is an `uint64_t`). Clearly every line is touching the state, and modifying it, so each statement depends on the one right before it. To contrast, here's xorshift1024+:

```
uint64_t s0 = s[ p ];
uint64_t s1 = s[ p = ( p + 1 ) & 15 ];
s1 ^= s1 << 31; // a
s1 ^= s1 >> 11; // b
s0 ^= s0 >> 30; // c
return ( s[ p ] = s0 ^ s1 ) * 1181783497276652981LL;
```

Here, the global state is in the `uint64_t s[16], p` variables. Given that, it's perhaps not crystal clear but at least somewhat hinted at, that the line with the `// c` comment is *not* sharing any state with the line before it. Thus, it's doing both shifts and an XOR (i.e. "work") that's independent from the similar work being done right before it. So a superscalar processor might be able to run those two lines in parallel, more or less.

Comment: I'd say it's an ILP thing, pipelining, superscalar are just ways to achieve ILP. There are other methods like OoO and VLIW that are also widely used.

Comment: @user3528438 Sold! Thanks. But isn't VLIW assuming the compiler is choosing the instructions to achieve parallelism, rather than the instructions "looking" sequential, but becoming parallel in practice? There's some kind of difference there, I think ...

Comment: It's true that VLIW doesn't fit quite well into the original question.